# jQuery DOM Update from Click Handler

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-events

I want to show a `div` that serves as a loading screen when invoking an Ajax update from a click handler that can take a second or two, something like:

```
var loadingControl;

loadingControl = $("#loading"); // Is initialized after DOM Ready

$('#updateLink').click(function (e) {
    loadingControl.show();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'http://some.url',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#divToUpdate').html(data);
        },
        error: handleAjaxError
    });

    loadingControl.hide();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `loading` div does not show.  I suspect that is because the DOM does not update until the `click` handler completes.  Is that correct?

How can I restructure this code to allow the DOM to update after the call to `.show()`, so that the loading screen `div` is visible while `.ajax` is running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ajax call is asynchronous, so the code continues to run. Therefore your `loadingControl.hide()` function is getting called right after the ajax starts, try moving your `loadingControl.hide();` inside the `success` function.

```
$('#updateLink').click(function (e) {
    loadingControl.show();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'http://some.url',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#divToUpdate').html(data);
            loadingControl.hide();
        },
        error: handleAjaxError
    });


    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I added a `complete` function to unhide the loading screen whether the ajax calls or fails.